# How to get a href of drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

checking this sample. http://html5demos.com/drag

i was wonder how to get when You drop a < li >. (by href)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly: You want to get the href attribute of the element being dropped? If so you can view source on that page and look on line 131.

```
var el = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));
```

the `el` element has an `href` attribute so you can do: `el.href` and that will give you the href you are asking for and in this case it will return `html5demos.com/drag#`